# Is f necessarily continuously differentiable under given conditions?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

$f_m:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is function series that are integrable  on any compact segment , $2\pi$ periodic and  $f_m \overset{u}{\rightarrow} f$ converging uniformly. Moreover for all $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ and all $m\ge 1$ 
$$|\hat{f_m}|\le \frac{1}{|n|^3}$$

- Is f necessarily continuously differentiable under given conditions? prove or give a counter example.
- now you are given that $f_m$ is continuous for all $m$ is f necessarily continuously differentiable now ? prove or give a counter example.

since we are not given that $f_m$ is continuous in first question i'm trying to use it to "build" a counter example for the first question .

but i can't understand why are we given that information about fourier coefficients and how to use it .

have no clue on the second question and in general how one can prove a function is continuously differentiable if the function itself is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the inequality is
$$
|\widehat{(f_m)}_n|\le\frac{1}{n^3}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Since $f_m\to f$ uniformly, it follows that
$$
|\hat f_n|\le\frac{1}{n^3}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
The Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly, as well as the series derived term by term. However, we only know that $f_m$ and $f$ are integrable. We could change their values on a finite set of points and the Fourier coefficients would be the same. We cannot conclude that the sum of the Fourier series is equal to $f$. Consider for instance $f$ he periodic extension of $f(x)=0$ if $0<x<2\,\pi$ and $f(0)==1$. All conditions are met, but $f$ is not continuous.

If we know that $f$ is continuous, it will be equal to the sum of the Fourier series, which is a $C^1$ function because of the decay of the Fourier coefficients.